# scriptlet gets executed wrongly

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

The following code:

```
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="<%cart.removeItem(0);%>">Click me</button>
```

is suppose to be executed when the button is clicked. However,

```
 "<%cart.removeItem(0);%>"
```

is being executed when page is refreshed without clicking the button. Why is this happening?

Cheers.

Heres the full source.

```
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="cart" scope="session" class="myBeans.cart" />
    <%
    cart.addItem("aji", "1000", "1");
    cart.addItem("ewer", "200", "1");
    cart.addItem("dfwerweji", "10", "1");
    cart.addItem("ldsjioi", "1320", "1");

    String[] prodNames = cart.getProdNames();
    double[] prices = cart.getProdPrices();
    int[] qtys = cart.getProdQtys();
    double total = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<prodNames.length; i++){
    total += prices[i]*qtys[i];
    out.println(prodNames[i]);
    out.println(" " + prices[i] + " ");
    out.println("<input type=text name=newQty value=" + qtys[i] + ">");
    out.println(" " + prices[i] * qtys[i]);
    }
    %>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="<%cart.removeItem(0);%>">Click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up your languages here. I suspect that 'cart' is a Java object, and you can only modify JavaScript objects on the client side. You would have to have something like this to make it work:

```
<script> 
  doRemoveFirst = function() { new Ajax.Request('removeFirst.page'); }; 
</script>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="doRemoveFirst();">Click me</button>
```

Then have a page on the server called 'removeFirst' that will remove that object from the Java object (maybe kept in session?) and you can update your page accordingly.

**EDIT**: Here's an image to help. Everything left of diagonal is client-side, while everything right is server-side.

[image: This Image]

**EDIT 2**: To remove and fix the page for the user

I would say something like (assuming jQuery) this might work for you.

```
$(".item-row").first().remove(); 
$(".item-row").each(function(idx, el) {
  var elem = $(el).children().find('.index-cell');
  elem.text(+elem.text() - 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes cart is a javabean object. Your code, 'new Ajax.Request('removeFirst.page');', whats the point of removeFirst.page?

Comment: I have edited and put in the full source. Hope that can give you a better understanding of my code. Thanks

Comment: @user859385: You are mixing client and server-side objects and actions. 'cart' is ONLY available server-side, while the button click is client-side. The point of my Ajax.Request (which is just the Prototype Library shorthand for Ajax requests) is to call back to the server telling it to do execute that page. On that page, the code removes item 0 from the cart object, then you either re-render the client-facing page, inject updated data, or just hide/delete it with Javascript. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I understand what you are coming at. However, even if i reload the page, how am i going to get the javabean object propety from javascript. Ive researched alot and i could not find any mechanism for javascript and javabean to work together except javascriptbean. But javascriptbean is way too complicated.

Comment: @user859385: Maybe my picture will help you understand better what I mean.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. The fact that "a picture tells thousand words" is true. That clearly explained what i needed to do. Very much appreciated

Comment: Well im still stuck after making an ajax request. I do not know how to delete my item from javascript.

Comment: I do not understand how your updated code works. I do not know where to place the javascript code you provided. Do you need me to send you my javabean object source code? Theres a function in my javabean object, which is, removeItem(int i), to remove an item from a specific index.